# Local notifications that expire while device is turned off are lost

Tags: ios

If my app queues a local notification but then the device is turned off while the notification is due to fire, then upon restarting the device there is no indication there ever was a notification that fired.

Same thing seems to happen with calendar alarms.

This doesn't seem like the correct behavior to me from a user's perspective - if the notification were a calendar reminder for something very very important, and I happened to reboot at the very instant it fired, then I've lost that important reminder, even if my device were only turne3d off for 3 seconds, if the notification was due to fire in the 3 seconds its lost forever.

Am I missing something?

Comment: File a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573013/uilocalnotification-when-iphone-switched-off

Comment: The answer to that duplicate question is incorrect - a local notification *does* persist a reboot, it is not lost *unless* its fire time was while the device was switched off. Persisting notifications over reboot is reasonable behavior, losing those that would have fired while the device is turned off is not IMO. It means the app has no idea what might have been lost or what not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say this is by design: if you keep a device turned off for 1 month, you don't want it to display 1 months worth of worthless notifications. Also, iOS devices are designed to be always on; should you need to be unreachable you just turn on airplane mode which will disable all wireless/cellular communications but you'll still get the notifications.