# How to get notification when mobile in switch off mode

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, reminders, alarms

Iam try to do a small application in that i want to show alarm/notification even when iphone is in switch off..

Please tell which one is best like localnotification/pushnotification/ add to reminder..

Comment: Do you want the notification to go off in a certain time?

Comment: How will you show notifications when the phone is switched off ?? HOW ?? The pending notifications will be received once the phone is switched on again.

Comment: No you cant get Notification when iDevice is Switch off

Comment: @croyneaus4u normally we get alarm even our mobile is switched off like that i want..

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) because most of the alarm apps use that. I am not sure whether UILocalNotifications are fired when the device is switched off. See this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284740/local-notifications-that-expire-while-device-is-turned-off-are-lost)  that has a similar discussion.